# Problem in installing package : illuminate/database

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I just tried to install illuminate/database package outside of laravel framework in my own project and got this error:

```
composer require illuminate/database

Using version ^7.11 for illuminate/database
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for illuminate/database ^7.11 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[v7.11.0].
    - Conclusion: remove illuminate/container v5.8.36
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v5.8.36
    - illuminate/database v7.11.0 requires illuminate/container ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.0, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.1, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.2, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.3, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.4, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.5, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.6, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.7, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.8, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.1.0, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.1.1, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.1.2, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.1.3, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.10.0, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.10.1, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.10.2, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.10.3, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.11.0, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.2.0, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.2.1, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.2.2, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.3.0, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.4.0, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.5.0, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.5.1, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.5.2, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.6.0, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.6.1, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.6.2, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.7.0, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.7.1, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.8.0, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.8.1, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.9.0, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.9.1, v5.8.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.9.2, v5.8.36].
    - Installation request for illuminate/container (locked at v5.8.36) -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.8.36].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

is it possible to install this package in another way?

do you have any ideas how can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the output, `illuminate/database` requires at least v7 of `illuminate/container`. Any other requirement in your `composer.json` does not allow that, so you should check which one that is. If there is no direct requirement of that container package in your JSON, you can run the following command to check for a indirect dependency:

```
composer why-not illuminate/container:7.0.0
```

But as far as I see, you try to mix Laravel v5 and v7. That is usually not a good idea - either stick to v5 with all your dependencies or upgrade everything to v7